# How to specify the path to jar in java source code?

Tags: java, import, jar, classpath

In my program, I am importing some functions defined in a class file in jar. And whenever I compile or run the code, I always need to specify the path to the file with `-cp ./:/path/to/jar`.

Is there any way that I can specify the jar path in my source code? So that I don't need to type `-cp ./:/path/to/jar` every time I compile or run the code?

Comment: Use a build tool like Maven or Gradle, you won't need to type `-cp` anymore.

Comment: It is really unclear what you're trying to do. Runtime? Do you compile something in runtime?

Comment: @lexicore nah, it's not just for compiling, but also for running. Once you decided to include a jar file, you always need to use `-cp` whenever your compile or run. This is annoying in a way that the user should be aware of what to do when launching the program in command line. So I am looking for a clean way that whenever I compile I just `javac /path/to/source/file/` and when I run I just `java classname`

Comment: But for runtime you don't need to specify JAR paths in your source code.

Comment: @lexicore Yes, I don't have to specify jar path in source code for run time, but I have to `-cp`. This is what I don't like and want to get rid of.

Comment: The easiest is to build a fat JAR. With `maven-shade-plugin`, for instance. You'll get just one JAR with all the dependencies in it and you can just run this one JAR without any additional classpath.

Comment: If you were not using Maven before, this might be a bit too heave to learn it for the task. Try to find a fat-jar packaging tool for whatever build system you were using.

Answer (score 0):

The classpath is used by the VM to find your classes. You cannot specify it in the source code. If you are looking for a shortcut then you can write a wrapper script that calls your program with the classpath that you desire.

Answer (score 0):

You could change your packaging approach instead. If you created a 'fat jar' containing your code and the other classes from the other jar(s) you are dependent on, then you could run your app with a 'java -jar yourjar.jar'. Maven Shade is one way to do this, see: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/